# How to POST using WebRequest?

Tags: c#

Using WebRequest How to POST things, Should I use GetRequestStream? and how to format POST string

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    // write to the body of the POST request
    writer.Write("param1=value1&param2=value2");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to HttpWebRequest, have a look at [WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx):

```
var values = new NameValueCollection();
values.Add("param1", "value1");
values.Add("param2", "value2");

new WebClient().UploadValues("http://www.example.com", values);
```